# Differentiate Dependency based on profile in Gradle file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to differentiate my dependencies based on different environments. I'm not getting correct env value along with correct conditions to categories dependency.

```
  def profile = project.hasProperty("spring.profiles.active") ? 
  project.property("spring.profiles.active") :
    System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active", 'local')
  bootRun {
   systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", profile
    }
```

I expect the output something like below but profile variable is not getting correct profile value

```
  dependencies{
  if(profile == "dev"){
  compile('com.oracle:ojdbc6:+')
  }
  if(profile == "prod"){
  compile('commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4')
   }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can proceed differently by having `build_[profile].gradle` for each profile, where **[profile]** is the profile you pass as argument when you launch your application example ( via **-P** ) :

```
./gradlew -Pprod bootRun
```

So suppose you have 2 environment prod and local, in your `build.gradle` you will have :

```
def currentProfile;

if (project.hasProperty('prod')) {
    currentProfile = 'production';
    apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/build_prod.gradle');

} else if (project.hasProperty('local')) {
    currentProfile = 'local';
    apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/build_local.gradle'); 
} else {
    currentProfile = 'default profile';
    apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/build_default.gradle');
}
println 'Current profile: "' + currentProfile + '"
```

You should also have 2 gradle files; `build_prod.gradle` and `build_local.gradle`, and there you could have different dependencies and configuration as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much.